# How get the max value from a group by?

Tags: sql, group-by, max

I want to do a `GROUP BY` by id_municipio and cbo, and than I want to select the cbo with max amount by id_municipio.

I have been trying:

```sql
SELECT id_municipio, cbo_2002, COUNT(*) as N_CBO
 FROM basedosdados.br_me_rais.microdados_vinculos
 WHERE ano = 2020 
 AND id_municipio IN (1200401, 3503208, 3543402)
 GROUP BY id_municipio, cbo_2002
```

And I get something like:

```
id_municipio | cbo_2002 | N_CBO
-----------------------
1200401      | 3860     | 250 
1200401      | 3548     |  28
1200401      | 4420     |  12
3503208      | 6851     |   5
3503208      | 3860     | 250
3503208      | 2204     | 350
3503208      | 5222     |1000
3543402      | 5222     |   2
3543402      | 7        | 780
3543402      | 6650     | 660
```

Now, I expect to have one row by each id_municipio and the cbo with the max value (n_cbo), something like:

```
id_municipio | cbo_2002
-----------------------
1200401      | 3860
3503208      | 5222
3543402      | 7
```

Comment: Similar question have been asked and answered many, many times. Why didn't any of those solutions work for you?

Comment: So you have some groups of rows and you want only the top one row from each group? Try searching with those terms and you'll find literally hundreds of solutions.

Comment: @HoneyBadger I'm begginer, I don't know how to fit the examples in my case. Another point, I didn't know the terms used to this search. Stu, thanks, it helped.

Comment: try this SELECT id_municipio, max(cbo_2002)  as N_CBO
 FROM basedosdados.br_me_rais.microdados_vinculos
 WHERE ano = 2020 
 AND id_municipio IN (1200401, 3503208, 3543402)
 GROUP BY id_municipio

Comment: @Naveed I dont thinks this is it. Because `cbo_2002` is not a number, is a classification. I want to count how many classificatins I have and select only the biggest classification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        id_municipio,
        cbo_2002,
        COUNT(*) AS n_cbo
    FROM
        basedosdados.br_me_rais.microdados_vinculos
    GROUP BY
        1, 2
)
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        id_municipio,
        cbo_2002,
        n_cbo,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY id_municipio, cbo_2002 ORDER BY n_cbo DESC
        ) AS rn
    FROM cte
)
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! This code is easy to understand. I thought it would solve, but as a result I'm having lots of `id_municipio` duplicated.

Comment: I think removing `cbo_2002` form PARTITION BY solved my problem! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
select   id_municipio
        ,cbo_2002
from    (select id_municipio 
               ,cbo_2002
               ,row_number() over (partition by id_municipio order by N_CBO desc) as rn
         from   t) t
where    rn = 1
```

| id_municipio | cbo_2002 |
| --- | --- |
| 1200401 | 3860 |
| 3503208 | 5222 |
| 3543402 | 7 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ngMSguAV?hide=2)